# How can i count the number of data that match the string text i have from this query?

Tags: php, mysql, html

```
mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT lo_category FROM questions where question_text = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["choice"]) . "'");
```

So from the query above i will get the lo_categories that match with the choice.How do i get the number of categories,eg

```
Category Cognitive : 3 matches
Category Psychomotor : 1 matches
Category Perception : 0 matches
```

`($_GET["choice"])` is from the html checkbox with multiple choices.
And this is my question table.

```
question_id  question_text               keyword  lo_category lo_domain
      1     Define the word paraphrase    Define  Knowledge   Cognitive 
      2     describe the meaning of NLP  describe Knowledge   Cognitive 
      3     describe the meaning of NLP  describe Perception  Psychomotor 
      4     describe the meaning of NLP  describe Receiving   Affective 
      5     Define this                    Define Knowledge   Cognitive
```

Updated with this ,there's error.Please help i'm so lost!!!

```
$yes=mysql_query("select lo_category, count(*) from questions where question_text='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["choice"]) . "' group by lo_category order by lo_category");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($yes)) {
    echo '<b>Category :</b> ' . $row['lo_category'] . ',' . $row['count(*)'] . '<br />'; 
}
```

Please help me i'm a beginner in this..Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: May I suggest you get the value of $_GET['choice']; and assign it to it's own variable. Then sanitize it and make sure it is clean! You are asking for an SQL injection attack by taking direct URL parameter entries and inserting them into your SQL query. Someone can wreak total havock with your database like that. As it stands, your data is hugely at risk.

Comment: How to do that ? Please help me

Comment: Read up on sanitizing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this would be something like:

```
select lo_category, count(*) from questions where question_text=<choice> group by lo_category order by lo_category
```

Comment: Hi,i got this error 'Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\next.php on line 25'
at this line' $yes=mysql_query("select lo_category, count(*) from questions where question_text='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["choice"]) . "' group by lo_category order by lo_category");'

Comment: What is the value of $_GET["choice"] ?

Comment: question_text that is selected from the html checkbox `echo '<input type="checkbox" name="choice[' . $row["question_text"] .  ']" value="2" /> ' . $row["question_text"] . '<br />';`

Comment: it's String selected from checkbox.Multiple selections.

Comment: No from the code above, the value is "2" not the question. As well ast the choice is an array, not a string. What you meant was name="choice" value=$row["question_text"]

Comment: so what should i put in the value if i wan the choice to be the question_text so that i can run the group query ?

Comment: Exactly as I showed above. where I said name="choice" value=$row["question_text"]

Comment: ok,` echo '<input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="' . $row["question_text"] . '" /> ' . $row["question_text"] . '<br />';` still giving me the error.

Comment: here's my form `echo "<form name='whatever' action='next.php' method='GET'>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qsq))
{

 echo '<input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="' . $row["question_text"] . '" /> ' . $row["question_text"] . '<br />';

}

echo"<br>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='submit' /></form>";`

Comment: This isnt in the same form as you're trying to display the results is it? eg, it hasnt actually had the form data back yet?

Comment: Yeah.This is the form that gives the `GET[CHOICE]`  While this is the one to display the group result `$yes=mysql_query("select lo_category, count(*) from questions where question_text='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["choice"]) . "' group by lo_category order by lo_category");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($yes)) {
 echo '<b>Category :</b> ' . $row['lo_category'] . ',' . $row['count(*)'] . '<br />'; 
}
 
`

Comment: Please clarify, its the same PHP page?

Comment: Different page.After select ,click button to go to the next.php(another page)  and also is the button that submit the CHOICE

Comment: Can you do me a favor and at the top of your next.php code, can you put "print_r($GET);" for me, and post the result

Comment: I think the problem is the choices is in array so i can't use it in the query `"select lo_category, count(*) from questions where question_text='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["choice"]) . "' group by lo_category order by lo_category");` because it is multiple choice. Do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: Currently its NOT multi choice. So, can you post me the output as requested. To be multi choice we can fix later.

Comment: Array ( [choice] => Array ( [Define the word paraphrase] => 2 [describe the meaning of NLP] => 2 ) )

Comment: Then thats why, your form is still "<input type="checkbox" name="choice[' . $row["question_text"] . ']" value="2" /> ' . $row["question_text"] . '<br />';" not the code we changed, each value is 2.. this is why I know

Comment: The form I corrected would have given you the get choice with a single text entry of the last question selected

Comment: But i changed it to this already ` echo '<input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="' . $row["question_text"] . '"' /> ' . $row["question_text"] . '<br />';` Isit stuck or something with the old code ? i save it already ...

Comment: you sure you uploaded the file? or hit refresh in your browser not just "back"?

Comment: Hey i got it .THANK YOU VERY MUCH =D

Comment: Hi,now i have problem with the multiple choices.The query only manage to give me result of 1 choice but i have actually selected a few.

Comment: Always get a working thing before breaking it with something new. So, to make your query work with an array, you need to parse through your array, to test for question = choice1 or choice 2 or choice 3 or choice 4.. to choice n..  You should also rename your variable to "choice[]" so that php sees the results as additiona not overwriting the original value

Answer (score 1):

```
select lo_category, count(lo_category) as countOflo_category group by lo_category
```

Comment: formatted your answer feel free to rollback anything you don't want

Comment: So,by echo this query i will get the result i wan ?

Comment: help!! i got this error Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\next.php on line 25 which is the query line

Comment: Yes,it worked.But i need them to match with the choice then only do the grouping to count categories

Comment: Try using COUNT(DISTINCT(lo_category)) AS countOflo_category

Comment: Then you have countOflo_category as a returned value / variable which should count only distinct categories. Is that what you need?

Comment: i have to count how many falls into same category so i cannot use distinct .I think i have problem with the GET[CHOICE] which im discussing below..You have any ideas how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

$result =mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT lo_category FROM questions where question_text = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["choice"]) . "'");

mysql_num_rows($result)this will return the noumber of row your reslut set contains

Comment: Or could simply add the COUNT() function before the DISTINCT function and avoid an additional mysql_num_rows() call.